# Using a for each loop to check list of possible passwords

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently learning actionscript 3 and I am stuck in a problem, just want someone to lead me towards what am doing wrong or explain it to me.  What am trying to do is match an Array of possible passwords to the correct password and trace if the password is correct or not.  This is what I have so far.

```
var passWords:Array = ["catdog", "fatcow", "yoda", "petergriffin"];
var userPassword:String = "petergriffin";
var wrongPassword:Boolean = false;


for each(var p:String in passWords)//checking each possible password for correct match
{ 
            if(p == userPassword)
            {
                trace("The password was found in the list");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do it would be to use AS3's `indexOf` function for arrays:

```
if(passWords.indexOf(userPassword) != -1) {
     trace("The password was found in the list");
}
```

`indexOf` returns the index of the element in the array (surprisingly!). But if the element is not in the array, then it returns -1.